# Script that finds the number of rows per year for all date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a script that will return the number rows per year for all dates columns from all the tables in the database.

For example, if we have transactional tableX with N columns , so I need dynamic script which will loop through all columns in  a table and find columns with DATE or DATETIME data type. After that it will run through the list of date type columns and return the number of rows per YEAR(with name ex.ColumnDate)

```
Output: 
Table Name1:
DateColumn1:
Year    Number Rows


DateColumnM:
Year    Number Rows


Table NameN:
DateColumn1:
Year    Number Rows


DateColumnM:
Year    Number Rows
```

Comment: You can use Information schema views to get all the date columns and use that to write dynamic sql queries.

Comment: I so far have a script that will provide me with all the tables in the database a long with the number of rows in each table.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify for which SQL Server, so I'm assuming Microsoft SQL Server, 2008 or later...

This code does what you need I think... just replace "MyTable" with the table name you're interested in:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000);
DECLARE @tableName sysname;
DECLARE @columnName sysname;

DECLARE theCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
       AND DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN theCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TabelName], ' + 
               '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' +
               'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + 
               ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [Count] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
               ' GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC (@sql);
    FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;
END
CLOSE theCursor
DEALLOCATE theCursor;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.

Yes I am using SQL Server 2008.

I am not too advanced with SQL language yet, so when I ran the query it gave me a "successfully completed", however does not show any tables.

Comment: And if you want more than one table, just change the WHERE clause in the cursor definition.

Comment: AH, sorry, if you look at the "Messages" tab, it will show SQL, which you can copy and paste to execute.

Comment: OR, you can change the "Print @sql;" statement, to be "EXEC(@sql);" and it will execute it for you as it runs

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the EXEC ... 

Note, if the SELECT statement in the cursor definition returns no rows, then this entire script will do nothing.  You can run JUST that SELECT to ensure it picks up exactly the table and columns you're interested in.

Comment: Make SURE you've edited the SELECT in the cursor definition to change "MyTable" to the table you're actually interested in.  Or if you want more than one table, change the where clause to "WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('MyFirstTable', 'MySecondTable', MyThirdTable')" for example.

Comment: Perfect I tried it out and it looks to be working! Can't thank you enough. Would there be any possible way to do this search without specifying the table in the select statement? Such as going through every table in the database?

Comment: Yes, just leave out the WHERE clause in the CURSOR definition entirely.  But that'll likely pick up some 'system' tables you don't much care about.  I don't know if that's an issue for you or not.  You can always just run that initial SELECT statement by itself in order to see what tables and columns will be selected.  Add an ORDER BY TableName and it'll be easy to peruse it.  You can tweak the WHERE clause to get exactly the tables you want.

Comment: Be sure to click the up arrow next to the answer if you find it useful.  Thanks :-)

Comment: I see that makes sense. What I did was deleted only part of the where clause (one which said where name is this) and left the where data_type is this part. I checked by running the select statement separately and found it shows all the tables I'm looking to get data from. So this is good. However when I run the query it provides the right table information, but there is a lot outputs with just a blank rows. Any ideas?

Comment: And I would but apparently I need 15 reputation :( is there anything else I could do to show your answer worked?

Comment: To my above comment I believe some outputs are not showing any rows, because as you explained before the tables associated with that output has no rows, so the result will show no rows. Is there any way to only display the tables with rows? Right now for that select statement 99 tables show up, and when I run the command 99 outputs come, to which 28 of them have results cause the other 71 dont have rows in those tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more long-winded approach, but I think it gives you what you are looking for?

Run the following query in the database you want to report on:

```
--Make a list of tables to target
DECLARE @HitList TABLE (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName VARCHAR(1024),
    SchemaName VARCHAR(1024),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO
    @HitList
SELECT
    t.name,
    s.name,
    c.name 
FROM 
    sys.columns c 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE 
    c.system_type_id = 61; --DATETIME

--Now get the count of rows per year for each table in the list
DECLARE @Id INT = 1;
DECLARE @Count INT;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @HitList;
CREATE TABLE #Results (
    Id INT,
    [Year] INT,
    [RowCount] INT);
WHILE @Id <= @Count
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT 
        @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #Results SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Id) + ', YEAR([' + h.ColumnName + ']), COUNT(*) FROM [' + h.SchemaName + '].[' + h.TableName + '] GROUP BY YEAR([' + h.ColumnName + ']) ORDER BY 1;'
    FROM
        @HitList h
    WHERE
        Id = @Id;
    EXEC(@SQL);
    SELECT @Id = @Id + 1;
END;

--Output the results
SELECT
    h.TableName + '.' + h.SchemaName + '.' + h.ColumnName AS [Table],
    r.[Year],
    r.[RowCount]
FROM
    @HitList h
    INNER JOIN #Results r ON r.Id = h.Id
ORDER BY
    h.TableName,
    h.ColumnName,
    r.[Year];
```

For example, I ran this against one of my SQL Server 2008 databases to get these (partial) results:

```
Table                                           Year    RowCount
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2008    1680
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2009    7978
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2010    15398
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2011    28769
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2012    35682
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2013    59047
ElecConsumptionForecast.Staging.LastReadingDate 2014    127668
```